# Compiler warning message

Tags: c, compiler-construction, compilation, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I have a piece of code when compiled gives me this warning

```
#define SKM_sk_set_cmp_func(type, st,cmp) \
        ((int (*)(const type * const *,const type * const *)) \
        sk_set_cmp_func(CHECKED_PTR_OF(STACK_OF(type), st), CHECKED_SK_CMP_FUNC(type, cmp)))

#define sk_X509_set_cmp_func(st, cmp) SKM_sk_set_cmp_func(X509, (st), (cmp))

static int mrs_X509_cmp_callback(const X509 **a, const X509 **b);

int foo()
{
       STACK_OF(X509) *certs;

       (void)sk_X509_set_cmp_func(certs, mrs_X509_cmp_callback);
}

In function foo:
warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression
```

Can you guys let me know how to get rid of the warning message?

Comment: Without knowing what type those are? Fat chance.

Comment: What is the prototype for `sk_X509_set_cmp_func()`? How did you declare `certs`?

Comment: Never ever tag questions like this both C++ and C.

Comment: I edited code to include the prototype for sk_X509_set_cmp_func()

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a couple different issues with your code.  First, `foo` is suppose to return an `int`, yet you aren't returning any type ... that will at the very least throw a compiler warning, if not compile at all.  Secondly, as it stands right now, it seems your macro is attempting a cast of a function pointer returned from `sk_set_cmp_func`, but then it seems you're attempting to cast that function pointer to `void` type ... at the very least, you should be casting that to a `void*` since you're returning a function pointer.  Still in the end though, the cast doesn't make any sense in the context of `foo` as it's written, since that function should be returning an `int` type.